# core data update attempt showing in table view but not persisting

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have an application that uses a `UItableview` and a single `UIViewController`. The `UIViewController` is used for all of **Add/Edit/View**

I am able to add and view then switch to edit. `The problem I am having is persisting the data in core data following an update.` Following an edit/update, the changes are visible in the Table View but upon application restart (or back from then forward to the table view) the changes are gone.

The tableview class sets the `NSManagedObject` in `prepareForSegue` as follows:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSManagedObject *selectedEntry = [fetchResultsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    DSAdd *wadd = [segue destinationViewController];
    if ([segue.identifier  isEqualToString: @"detailsSegue"])
    {
        wadd.callType = 2; //view details
        wadd.selectedEntry = selectedEntry;
    }
    else
    {
        wadd.callType = 0; //add
    }
}
```

In the view controller's header, I declare:

`@property (strong) NSManagedObject *selectedEntry;`

In the view controller's class I have the following Save method:

```
- (void) saveData
{
    DBUtils *dbu = [[DBUtils alloc] init];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [dbu managedObjectContext];
    if (isEditMode) //<-- THIS PART DOES NOT WORK
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",[_selectedEntry valueForKey:@"name"]); //prints old value
        [_selectedEntry setValue:_nameTF.text forKey:@"name"];
        NSLog(@"%@",[_selectedEntry valueForKey:@"name"]); //prints new value
    }
    else // <-- THIS PART WORKS
    {
        NSManagedObject *newItem;
         newItem = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entry" inManagedObjectContext:context];

       [newItem setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"catId"];
       [newItem setValue:_nameTF.text forKey:@"name"];
    } //else

    NSError *error;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
         NSLog(@"Failed to save - error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: what is _selectedEntry? A managed object

Comment: Yes. It is in the view controller's .h: @property (strong) NSManagedObject *selectedEntry;

Comment: its going into if block and did you print the _selectedEntry

Comment: Yes I tried that using:         NSLog(@"%@",[_selectedEntry valueForKey:@"name"]); in the if block. it shows the correct output. Tried before and after `setValue` and both are correct showing the old and new value

Comment: After save go to your Application folder of your IPhoneSimulator and check the .sqlite file and see if updated value is there or not

Comment: Not :)... Checked using sqlite3 command line... If it were updated, then the change would have been reflected after I restart my application but it is not being...

Comment: What is dbutil doing? You must use the same context as you used to fetch the object originally. Pass the context to your viewcontroller as well as the object

Comment: Two things.. what is "isEditMode"? It's not defined or set anywhere? Also, if your property is @property (strong) NSManagedObject *selectedEntry; then you should access it as  self.selectedEntry, not using the underlying instance variable _selectedEntry.

Comment: Why does isEditMode matter to answer my question? And why not access it as _selectedEntry if it is synthesized that way? This has nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald answer lead me to figure out what the error was... I was recreating the context even when it was already initialized. In my context method I added a check to verify if it is nil, then create it. Otherwise just return it. Duncan: The DBUtil class is where I put all generic DB Utility methods to reuse them across my apps. Thanks and please write an answer to get proper credit.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to make sure that NSManagedObject that you’re using belongs to a context you’re trying to save.

Then you need to check how this context is configured. If it is configured with persistent store coordinator, then save will commit to the store. If it is configured with a parent context, then save will push changes to the parent instead of saving to the store. In this case, you need to save the parent and if it is configured with another parent, then save that one. The changes will go to the store when the last parent, the on that is configured with persistent store coordinator is saved.

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be an issue with your context, try multi threading

[image: Try this]